# Need help figuring out how to avoid crashes in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, autosave

I pretty much know why my iPad app is crashing, but I'm having trouble coming up with a scheme to get around the scenario. The app is a jigsaw puzzle app. I've got a working version that's more stable than the one in the app store, but I still have a pesky problem I can't quite lick.

The root of the problem is a clash between user activity and automated saves. The save essentially stores the state of the puzzle as property list. The property list contains, among other things, a compilation of all the palettes in the puzzle, and for each palette, the details of all the pieces on that palette. It works well, except that user activity could change these details. A palette is essentially a UIView containing puzzle pieces as subviews. A user can move pieces around on a palette or move them from palette to palette.

I have the save process working in two phases. The first phase is kicked off by a timer. At regular intervals, this phase checks to see if there is some user activity that warrants a save. It sets a property `abortSave` to NO and then triggers a nonrepeating timer to wait for another period of time before starting phase two.

In phase two, the save takes place as long as `abortSave` is NO.

Meanwhile, if the user performs any operation that affects the save, `abortSave` is set to YES. The idea is that the delay between phase 1 and phase 2 is longer than it takes to perform a user operation, so if `abortSave` is NO, then it should be safe to do a save.

This process has eliminated 95% or so of the crashes, but I'm still getting crashes.

Of course, for decent performance of the app, the user activity as well as the save operation take place in background threads.

The type of circumstance I am running into is usually a mutation during fast enumeration, or something like that. Essentially, some user action is making a change during the save process. If I copy the object being fast enumerated and then work on the copy, it doesn't help. Sometimes the error will happen on the copy statement. If the object is an array, I don't use fast enumeration but use a regular for loop to work through the array. That helps a bit.

I hope this question isn't too generic. I suppose I could post some code, but I'm not sure how helpful it really would be. And I don't want to needlessly clutter the question.

One thing that I have not done yet, would be to use a flag working the other way:

`saveProcessActive` set to YES right before the save happens and set to NO when it finishes. Then all the user actions would have to be stalled if `saveProcessActive` is YES. The problem with this scenario is that it would result in a delay of the user action, potentially visible to the user, but maybe any delay is insignificant. It would only need to be as long as the save takes until its next check of `abortSave`. The aborted save process would then turn `saveProcessActive` to NO when it acknowledged the abort request. Is there a better solution?

Comment: You need to make your mutations thread safe. Without code, the only advice I can give you is to read the [concurrency guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: I see the documentation there immediately distinguishes between GCD and threads. So I should clarify that in my description, above, I am using GCD. When I mention a background thread, I'm using GCD to dispatch a task to a background thread. I don't control any threads directly. Anyway, thanks for the link. I'll read through and see if it suggests anything I'm not already doing.

Comment: Actually you're right that guide doesn't have exactly what I was thinking of! The asynchronous locks section in 'migrating from threads' section may be relevant. Check [this](http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2010/09/01/synchronization-using-grand-central-dispatch/) out though - provides more detailed instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to synchronize access to the data, both while saving and while altering it during normal play. As writing to file would likely take longer than making a copy, in order to minimize lock time you should make a copy while you have a lock, then release the lock and 
write the data to disk. There are a few ways to do this, but the easiest is an `@synchronised` block:

```
-(void) save
{
    NSDictionary *old = self.data;
    NSDictionary *new;
    @synchronized(old) {
        new = [old copy];
    }
    [self writeData:new];
}
```

And remember to synchronize changes too:

```
-(void) updateDataKey:(id)key toValue:(id)val
{
    NSDictionary *old = self.data;
    @synchronized(old) {
        old[key] = val;
    }    
}
```

`data` obviously doesn't need to be an `NSMutableDictionary`, it was just a convenient example.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like just the type of thing I was looking for. Seems like what Carl Veazey was also suggesting. I'll try this out and check your answer if it seems to do the trick. And then I can get rid of the two-step save process, which seemed like a kludge anyway.

Comment: I have a question about scope. In your save method, the `data` in parentheses is just a pointer to the same object self.data is a pointer to. Inside the @synchronized loop, the first `data` is a copy of the second `data`, presumably because there is a local scope. So isn't `writeData:data` writing the wrong `data`?

Comment: Just to add on to my previous remark, Xcode tells me Variable 'data' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization. Additionally, if I use a different name, it seems to have local scope because then there is an error on the `writeData` line saying the variable is undeclared.

Comment: I edited it to what I think is correct, leaving the old code as a comment. Since I'm just learning this, I leave it to someone else to finalize the correction or explain why the original was right.

Comment: I'm not seeing what you're saying. When you assign within a block, it stays assigned even leaving that block (when scope is larger). I think you and/or Xcode may have been confused a bit by the naming. I've altered it slightly, try this.

Comment: Looks like [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2832835) got clobbered by mine, it happens occasionally. The potential problem with what you put is that `self.data` could, in theory, be changed by another thread between requesting the lock and actually doing the copy, causing you to lock on the wrong instance. You could, I suppose, use `@synchronized(self)`, though I prefer as narrow a lock as possible.

Comment: Your edit clarifies things. In any case, I like to code with no warnings, so the `data = [data copy];` had to go. Good point about the `self.data`.

Comment: Won't this just synchronize the NSDictionary and not the objects stored inside it?  I don't think calling `copy` on an NSDictionary  makes copies of the contained objects also.

Comment: @AaronBrager The problem was that the dictionary itself was being altered while iterated over. This fixes that. Sure, if the contents were mutable, this doesn't prevent their mutation, but that's not the problem.

Comment: Granted, but it serves my purpose. The objects pointed to from the dictionary will be handled separately. If an absurd configuration results (dictionary points to an object that doesn't belong), the save cycle can simply be aborted and the next save cycle will take care of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Making a copy of the current game state in memory should be a fast action. When you want to save, make that copy, and then hand it to your background queue to save it with `dispatch_async()`. Doing it this way gets rid of all the concurrency issues because each piece of data is only ever accessed on a single queue.

---

EDIT: Here is how I've typically addressed such issues (untested):

```
- (void)fireSave:(NSTimer *)timer {
  id thingToSave = [self.model copyOfThingToSave];
  dispatch_async(self.backgroundSavingSerialQueue, ^{
    [self writeToDisk:copyOfThingToSave];
  }
}

- (void)saveLater {
  [self.timer invalidate];
  self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(fireSave:)
                                              userInfo:nil 
                                               repeats:NO];
}
```

Now, anywhere you modify data, you call `[self saveLater]`. Everything here is on the main thread except for `writeToDisk:` (which is passed a copy of the data). Since `writeToDisk:` always runs on its own serial queue, it also avoids race conditions, even if you ask it to save faster than it can.

Comment: Yes, it's fast. But there are still collisions, as I stated. The collision happens in that case with the copy, not with the save.

Comment: I am saying that the copy should occur on the main queue. The deeper point is that the data in question should only be accessed from the main queue, with only saving (of a copy) happening on a background queue. If that is true, then there can be no collisions.

Comment: He does mention in his question that the "user activity" is taking place on a background thread as well....

Comment: Ah; not sure what "user activity" is here. That kind of work should also follow the pattern above. Avoid accessing the same values on multiple queues. Pass immutable data to your background queues, and let them pass back the result onto the main queue (which ideally is the only one touching ivars). As much as possible, avoid locks; just keep everyone out of each others' business. This creates the most stable apps, and the ones more easily understood, debugged, and developed.

Comment: I thought I did. The user can move puzzle pieces around or move them between palettes. This is done with gestures. A long press for example might select all pieces of a certain color. The pieces are moved using GCD. The save process saves the locations of all pieces and what palette they are on. The save process by its very nature is tracking the user's business.